# load an external SVG sprite file into HTML

Tags: svg

I have this SVG data which I want to store in an external file and load it in, what is the best to do this? So I then can make use of it to load svgs such as:

```
<svg class="icon icon-heart"><use xlink:href="#icon-heart"></use></svg></span>
```

Comment: Could you reformulate the question as it is very hard to understand what's your objective. Is your data really composed of an `svg` , where you only have one `<use>` pointing to an external source, and a single `html` **closing** tag ? What will you do with this?

Comment: it'll just be a sprite

Comment: Then I'll assume it is for an `html` web page. This code doesn't make a sprite. It calls it. So you may "store" it in your `.html` file, or in a string to be used with javascript (so a `.js` file or even a `.json`  one if there are a lot of them ; but IMHO then it would make more sense to use js to retrieve the references and create those calls via DOM ).

Answer (score 1):

Things changed a bit since then.

As of now, you can call it from an external file like this:

```
<svg><use xlink:href="external.svg#icon-heart"></use></svg>
```

and load external svg into our HTML like this for example:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="external.svg" width="0" height="0"></object>
```

**Note:** This approach doesn't work in IE